# In Gmail, how may I get an accurate message preview before send?

Tags: gmail

Occasionally the Gmail Compose or Reply message's display of a HTML message does not accord with the message as it will be sent, and then shown in Sent. (Using latest Chrome.) For example, hard line breaks that appear in the Compose window are missing from the Sent form.

How may I view the actual sent form before sending?

Comment: Please add amore details like the web browser that you are using and the steps that you follow to add the hard line breaks. It also be helpful if you add the HTML of the body of the message in the when it's in compose mode and the HTML of the body of the sent message.

Comment: "the steps that you follow to add the hard line breaks." Pressing ENTER. How do you do it?

Comment: "It also be helpful if you add the HTML of the body of the message in the when it's in compose mode and the HTML of the body of the sent message." I can't see how that can be helpful in answering the actual question I asked, which is about getting a preview, not debugging the discrepancy.